# Save Inputed textField data into a csv file

Tags: ios

I want to save the inputed data from 3 textfields. I think I will store them in a CSV-file. The problem is that I want to display it in another viewController. or can I do it in a single view controller?

the user will type in their infon in the view controller1, then there is a called "Den här texten kommer att sparas" will show a NSString with all the information that is typed in, and that is what I want to store and show in some kind of list/table in the second view controller.

My question is: How can I access the NSString from the left viewController? Or is there an easier way to solve this problem, e.g. in a single view controller?

Comment: This shouldn't be considered as a problem. There is nothing wrong with having a transition between 2 view controllers. That of course if you are sure this is what you really want. You dont "access" your variable from the new view controller, instead you should pass it through. How are you transitioning between yours VCs ?

Comment: Currently is there no connections between the vcs exept a modal button

Comment: You should use `NSUserDefaults` which is much easier than managing your own csv file by hand... With it you can store/read an Array of strings with a dozen of lines of code...

Comment: You can achieve it by `@property` make `@property` of  `NSString` variable in second viewcontroller then pass the string into it while you are navigating to second viewcontroller. Or also you can make a `singleton` to keep value through whole application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are changing the ViewController using a storyboard segue, the easiest way would be to pass it using the `-prepareForSegue`method. You have to set the segue identifier in the storyboard, select the segue and set your identifier text in the attributes inspector.

You will need to create propertys in your destination ViewController for the objects you want to pass.

Add this to your `destinationViewController.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *tf1String;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *tf2String;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *tf3String;
```

Then import the `destinationViewController.h` file in your `firstViewController.h`file.

```
#import "destinationViewController.h"
```

Then add the following method to your `firstViewController.m`file

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER"]) {
        DestinationViewController *destinationVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        destinationVC.tf1String = [yourTextField1 text];
        destinationVC.tf2String = [yourTextField2 text];
        destinationVC.tf3String = [yourTextField3 text];
    }
}
```

You may have to change some variables names in order to get this code working.

Comment: - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender;;
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Segue"]) {
        ViewController *ViewController = [segue ViewController];
        ViewController.kronorString = [_kronor text];
        ViewController.literString = [_liter text];
        ViewController.literprisString = [_literpris text];
    }
}

Comment: on the second line "{" I got error. Expected identifier or "(". How do I solve that?

Comment: You have to delete the two `;;` at the end of `sender: (id)sender;;`

Comment: still same problem after deleting

Comment: It's working for me without the ;;, maybe it would help to delete the method and write it again. Does Xcode give more info of the problem?

Comment: Xcode says that there is no method definition for "prepareForSegue"

Comment: /Users/sandberg/Desktop/TankApp/TankApp/view2.m:15:1: Expected identifier or '('

Comment: I don't understand that, it works perfectly for me. May it would help to close and re-open Xcode.

Comment: have tried that too, but Btw where in the .m file am I supposed to write that part?

Comment: I'd recommend to add it at the end, just before the `@end`.

Comment: hmm, the read mark moves to another line depending on where in the code it is placed..

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the code-part with the error?

Comment: sorry, I can´t. need more reputation :(

Comment: /Users/sandberg/Desktop/TankApp/TankApp/view2.m:79:49: No visible @interface for 'UIStoryboardSegue' declares the selector 'ViewController'

Comment: In your destinationViewController.h file, do you have this part `@interface destinationViewController : UIViewController` (Or ... `: UITableViewController`) ?

Comment: @interface ViewController : UIViewController

Comment: Oh, If there wasn't the `: UIViewController` part, this would have been the problem. You have the `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` import in your .h file?

Comment: Then I don't understand why this error occurs. It would be interesting to know if the same error would also occur on another Xcode project created in your Xcode installation. I will create a project featuring this and let you know if it works and what to do to get rid of this problem

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to connect something up in the storyboard?

Comment: In order to get the segue working, you have to connect the button that should start the segue with the destination View Controller by dragging a line (ctrl + drag) and you have to connect the ViewControllers in the storyboard with the view classes by selecting the view controller (make sure that it has a blue border) and entering the name of the class that belongs to the ViewController. I have a [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8r1yn19c8w0cnvu/Screenshot%202014-04-18%2019.03.39.png) of this.

Comment: I will check that tomorrow, thank you for giving me your project.

Comment: Finished. The updated project is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5g60czjeohq0qa6/TankApp_edited.zip). I added a comment telling you what I have changed.